# Live append from a field

Tags: jquery, append, var

This is the code I have so far.

```
function editContent(){
    var content = $('input').val();
    $('span.title').html(content);
}


<input type="text" onKeyPress="editContent();" value="Typography" />
```

The problem is that when I change what's typed into the `input` it doesn't re-append. Can someone help me?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "input" ).on('change', function() {
    $('span.title').append($(this).val());
});
```

I did not get one point, do you really looking for .append, or .html(),
Because .append, will go on adding appending the changed value in the span title, you may be need .html,

If so use this:

```
$('span.title').html($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add

```
$('span.title').append(content);
```

in some event such as `onTextChanged`, or `onBlur` of the input.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you haven't handled the `change` event

Add the following code in document ready

```
$( "input" ).blur(function() {
    var content = $(this).val();
    $('span.title').append(content);
});
```